# Get-ChildItem to get line count of multiple csv's in Powershell without outputting the full path

Tags: powershell, csv, get-childitem, line-count

I'm trying to get the line count of multiple CSV files exported to a CSV file. But it keeps outputting the full path.

This is my Powershell code:

```
$FullPath = "\\Space\folder1\folder2"
$lineCount = “$FullPath\reports\LineCount.csv”
Get-ChildItem $FullPath *.csv |
    Select-Object -Property @(
    'FullName'
     @{ Name = "LineCount"; Expression = { 
        @(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1 ).Count
     }}
     ) |
    Export-CSV $lineCount -NoTypeInformation
```

Output right now looks like this:

```
FullName                          Count
\\Space\folder1\folder2\ab.csv    24 
\\Space\folder1\folder2\bc.csv    30 
\\Space\folder1\folder2\cd.csv    10
```

This is what I want:

```
FullName Count
ab.csv    24 
bc.csv    30 
cd.csv    10
```

Comment: Change `'FullName'` to `'Name'`